# Git file rename with branches and merges

Tags: git, rename

The following Gist explains my issue

[rename-test.sh](https://gist.github.com/muppettizer/7572541)

Basically, a file is renamed then modified in myBranch.

And another developer in master modifies the file with the original name.

Merging myBranch into master causing a merge conflict and I now have 2 files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my example rename-test.sh I adjusted the similarity index and now git thinks data.txt and data-renamed.txt are no longer separate files.

The merge command is:

git merge -X rename-threshold=20 myBranch

Answer (score 0):

Renaming is not the problem here. The problem is the conflicting change in both branches: a line was appended in both branches, and Git cannot know *who is right*. You have to tell it, by manually resolving the conflict.

If you make `data.txt` a bit longer, say 5 lines, and in `myBranch` you rename the file and append a line, and in master you *prepend* a line, the merge will work with no conflicts.

Comment: Any link with more details on this. When Git shas the renamed file how does it work out the file has been renamed? How does more content in the file give Git more details to work out the file is renamed.

Comment: I think Git doesn't "sha" filenames, it shas the total content of all the files together. Filenames just don't matter. Unfortunately I could not find a lot of detail on this in the Git Book: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository#Moving-Files